# matplotlib: colorspectrum in stackplot based on intensity

Tags: python, matplotlib

Folks,
I have vector [2,3,5,8,4,3,2,1] that I am plotting on y axis against range(10) as x axis. I am doing this using matplotlib's stackplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6]
x = range(8)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stackplot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

Now I have another vector [8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4], which is intensity for vector y. I need to use this intensity vector to color code my stackplot so that I can visualize the color spectrum. Intensity is out of 10. How do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by color code stackplot? The purpose of stackplot is to stack the components of different vectors vertically, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/stackplot_demo.html) and [here](http://www.betterevaluation.org/en/evaluation-options/stacked_graph)

Comment: Actually you are correct. Don't need to stack here. But I need something similar where I can see color coding for intensity on a graph. Not sure I need bar chart. May be scatter with area fill in with proper intensity?

Comment: Given that the question is about a stackplot but OP said in comments that this is not actually desired, the question needs to be either edited to state specifically what is needed (also updated according to [ask]) or closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some bar plot, is this what you want?
[image]

The corresponding code is as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                    
import numpy as np                                                                 

y = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6]                                                       
x = range(len(y))                                                                  

y2 = np.array([8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4]) / 10.0                                     

fig, ax = plt.subplots()                                                           
ax.bar(x, y, color=map(str, y2))                                                   

plt.show()
```